# Openlayers Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Hola buenas estoy trabajando con openlayers la v5.2.0, me muestra un error les muestro una captura.

Me estoy guiando con el ejemplo de pagina oficial:

[openlayersejemplo](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html)

he hecho lo mismo que el ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: to tuve ese problema justamente este error se deriva de la actualización de openlayers cambiaron algunas cosas entonces te recomiendo revisar este en enlace a mi me funciono suerte. http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/simple.html

Comment: esta es del 3.8 que me base hace un par de años https://codepen.io/barbalex/pen/fBpyb